# Docker not syncing files on linux

Tags: docker

I have a project that looks as such:

[image]

First I run:

```sh
sudo docker build buildnev -t myos-buildenv
```

Then:

```sh
sudo docker run --rm -it -v Spwd:/root/env myos-buildenv
```

But the files are not shared and I cannot run Make from the docker

How can I fix that?

This is my Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM randomdude/gcc-cross-x86_64-elf

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y nasm xorriso grub-pc-bin grub-common

VOLUME /root/env
WORKDIR /root/env
```

Comment: I assume `-v Spwd:/root/env` is a typo and you meant `-v $PWD:/root/env`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your run command isn't mounting your current directory, unless it's a typo you haven't corrected yet. When I posted this, it read `sudo docker run --rm -it -v Spwd:/root/env myos-buildenv` .

I think you meant `$PWD` or `$(pwd)` , like this:

```sh
sudo docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/root/env myos-buildenv
```

Comment: Oh god, I didn't see that. Thank you!